# Tips to improve the performance of Dynamic Workload Broker in Workload Scheduler?

Tags: dynamic, broker, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I am used to schedule thousands of jobs with dynamic agents, does anybody have suggestions to improve the performance of the Dynamic Workload Broker?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic agents, managed by Dynamic Domain Master jobs submission, are handled centrally and cause additional processing to the Master node. 
For this reason we suggest you to add an additional Mailman Server that specifically serves the Dynamic Workload Broker component to separate this activity from the other Mailman Server.

In this example the new mailman server is called Server A.

Example:
Display workstation=Workstation_DWB

Workstation Name | Type   |  Domain       |   Ignored| Updated On | Locked By 
------------  -------   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Workstation_DWB    broker    MASTERDM   --------04/24/2014

CPUNAME Workstation_DWB
      DESCRIPTION "This workstation was automatically created."
      OS OTHER
      NODE localhost TCPADDR 41114
      DOMAIN MASTERDM
      FOR MAESTRO
        TYPE BROKER
        AUTOLINK ON
        BEHINDFIREWALL OFF
        FULLSTATUS OFF
        SERVER A
END